# large link when using $_get

Tags: php, get

i am processing a activation link.which looks like this.

```
localhost/actvte/validate.php?type=activate&geo=define&
value=227755RYQBENU5G8WE7RFPO6CD6Z#MJ1H1FA@G#IZWZ53903
&target=loaded&resrc=G6MYMI2R67727229911380184297841084713071U8VUYIGR
&master=user@gmail.com
```

but when i use $_get['value'] i get o/p only "227755RYQBENU5G8WE7RFPO6CD6Z".after this whole link becomes useless.if i do

```
  echo $_get['target']; or echo $_get['master'];
```

it says `undefined variable` '`target`' or '`master`'.

so how can i process this large link.

Comment: everything after the # is client side only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is use the `urlencode()` function in PHP on the string before putting it in the GET. This way your string becomes `227755RYQBENU5G8WE7RFPO6CD6Z%23MJ1H1FA%40G%23IZWZ53903` and not `227755RYQBENU5G8WE7RFPO6CD6Z#MJ1H1FA@G#IZWZ53903` as special characters cannot be used in the query string.

Hashes for example will never even be send by the browser to the server, so everything behind that will not reach you.

Please look at [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for more information about the URI syntaxing (including hashes).

Comment: Once you get it in your application, simply do a urldecode().

Comment: @sid — Assuming you use proper escaping (i.e. prepared statements and bound variables), it will store whatever you put in it.

Comment: @Boy — No. It will come into the application through `$_GET`, where it will have *already been decoded*. Using `urldecode` on it will double decode it and possibly break data.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't test it out it so you are probably right Quentin.

Answer (score 2):

By not using or properly encoding the fragment identifier (#).

Answer (score 1):

You should not use # in the URL but encode it some way, or use another character.

Answer (score 1):

The first `#` in a URL indicates the start of the fragment identifier. If you want to send it as data rather then a separator component of a URL then you need to express it as `%23`.